# "Correlated scalar subqueries must be aggregated" error despite having aggregated correlated scalar subqueries? - Spark SQL

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql, aggregation

I have a query that resembles:

```
SELECT (SELECT first(b.id) FROM table_b b WHERE b.person = a.student LIMIT 1) student_id,
       (SELECT first(b.id) FROM table_b b WHERE b.person = a.teacher LIMIT 1) teacher_id,
       'additional_field' AS additional_field
FROM table_a  a
```

This yields the following error:

```
The SQL expression for node [ SQLNode7 ] is invalid. Reason: [ Correlated scalar subqueries must be aggregated: GlobalLimit 1
```

Note that this query works perfectly fine in Redshift (without the `first()`)

Initially, I didn't add the `first()` aggregation, but I did so after getting this error. However, this error still persists even after adding it.

Some other things I've tried:

- using `max()` instead of `first()`: same error
- trying `max(first())`: error stating `Reason: [ It is not allowed to use an aggregate function in the argument of another aggregate function. Please use the inner aggregate function in a sub-query.`

Have I not aggregated this query correctly? Is there anything else I can try to "aggregate" my query as per this error?

---

Min Reproducible Example:

Input Tables:

```
table_a 
student teacher
A       Z
B       Z
C       Z
    
    
table_b 
id  person
1   A
2   B
3   C
4   Z
```

Output:

```
table_c 
student_id  teacher_id
1           4
2           4
3           4
```

Comment: You have a `LIMIT 1`, which is unnecessary if you're using an aggregate.  Also, data has no implicit order, so `LIMIT 1` should have an `ORDER BY` before it, such as `ORDER BY id LIMIT 1` *(processes only the one row with the lowest `id`)*.  Even then it's unclear what you want; `FIRST()` is more similar to `MIN()` than `MAX()`.  Please include a trivial example to demonstrate what you're trying to do, as advised here: [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952)

Comment: Added the min reproducible example

Comment: If there is always only one matching row, why not just do a join?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn’t understand the use of `LIMIT 1`: delete it and wrap your sub queries in an aggregate function - `MIN()` looks like a good choice - adding the obligatory `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT
 (SELECT MIN(b.id) FROM table_b b WHERE b.person = a.student) student_id,
 (SELECT MIN(b.id) FROM table_b b WHERE b.person = a.teacher) teacher_id,
  'additional_field' AS additional_field
FROM table_a a
GROUP BY 3
```

Comment: I doubt that aggregating the correlated sub-query is correct.  As far as I can tell the OP wants one id from TableB per row in TableA.  *(How the OP wants to determine which row's id they want, however, is ambiguous.)*

Comment: @mat I agree OP’s query is odd, and probably even not what’s intended, but nevertheless this fixes the error, which answers the question as stated.

Comment: Changing it to `SELECT 1, 2, 'additional_field' AS additional_field` would also remove the error ;)

Comment: @mat true, but even that has value because only after the error is fixed can OP evaluate the output and start iterating towards the desired solution; while the error remains, no progress can be made.

Comment: Got this error: `The SQL expression for node [ SQLNode7 ] is invalid. Reason: [ 
mismatched input 'first' expecting {')', ',', '-'}`. The `first(b.id)` is highlighted. Not sure why this is the error, but I replaced `first` with `min` and re-ran. I added a min reproducible example to my post too

Comment: @Ricardo sorry, I didn’t notice the use of `first()` - remove it. See edited answer.

Comment: I'm running my job now with this change, but isn't the correlated subquery technically not aggregated if we remove the `first()`?

Comment: @Ricardo I've improved the query - see new version in answer.